# Can SQL Injection happen other than input Form?

Tags: javascript, php

I use to hear that SQL injection happens when there is input field to make query to database.

I have lots of clickable buttons at CSS menu in index.html , when clicked it performs AJAX:

```js
<script>function bRowse(value) {
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","product.php?q="+value,true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;}}}</script>
```

JS will past the 'q' which is VALUE of each buttons to a PHP page to perform sql:

```
$sql = "SELECT item, price FROM product WHERE item='".$_GET['q']."';
```

This AJAX works fine. My question is:

1) This is buttons without input field, can SQL injection still happen in this case?

Really appreciate some expert opinions, thanks.

Comment: The injection is nothing to do with your JS, as the code that constructs and executes the query is in PHP.

Comment: Never leave parameters unescaped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that can still happen. I could execute your endpoint using `curl` or a tool like `Postman`, and send whatever value I want.

Comment: U scared me..so I still have to make prepared statment??

Comment: Is prepared statement enough to avoid this?

Comment: Yes, you must always ensure that security is handled server side. Yes, prepared statement will prevent SQL injection

Comment: @P.Lau - Yes, **always** used a prepared statement.